# How can I add a footer in the first page without missing the page numbering for other pages?

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

My objective is to add a footer only in the first page of my document, but the problem is that the page numbering is missing. How can i please fix this issue and have the footer only in the first page without missing the page numbering for all pages?
Here is the code I'm using:

before `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{my sentence}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

and after `\maketitle`:

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyfoot[L]{..footer sentence..} 

\begin{document} 
  \title{..the tiltle..} 
  \maketitle 
  \thispagestyle{fancy} 
  \begin{abstract} ..the abstract.. \end {abstract} 

  ..\\ ..the body.. \newpage ... \newpage ... 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where on the first page is the page number supposed to be displayed?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: on the right side of the footer..

Comment: `\fancyhf{}` remmoves everything. Remmove that line.

Comment: ok Johannes_B, i remmoved  \fancyhf{} and now i have the page number only on the first page.

Comment: here is a compilable document:

Comment: I think the problem is with the IEEEtran class..

Comment: when i use \documentclass{article}  instead, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Please [add](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/404736/edit) information needed to answer the question into the question (see the links in Bobyandbob's comment). Questions should be self-explaining without the need to read several additional comments. Comments can be removed or moved to chat.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this on a single page, I like to use tikzpagenodes.  (Don't forget to run it twice.)

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document} 
  \title{..the tiltle..}%
  \maketitle 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=base west] at (current page footer area.south west) {my sentence};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{abstract} ..the abstract.. \end {abstract} 

  ..\\ ..the body.. \newpage ... \newpage ... 

\end{document}
```